# CKEditor is not working after adding AJAX code

Tags: jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor which is working but if I add an AJAX code for submitting data then CKEditor is not displaying. Please check it.

If I remove the script then it will display

```js
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
     CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false;
     
     
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#addmail").click(function(){
        var editor1 = $('#editor1').val();
            $.ajax(
            {
                url:'process.php?key=aus',
                type:'POST',
                data:{'editor1='+editor1},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $("#table-container").html(data);
                },
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    
    <textarea name="mailbody" id="editor1" class="form-control" ></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="addmail" id="addmail">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure if this occurred from copying the code but you have a syntax error `data:{'editor1='+editor1}`. You want to add pass the data as a simple object, which first of all means, to drop the `+` and then drop the `=`. jQuery will take care of adding that for you.

Correct therefore would be: `data: {'editor1': editor1},`.